# Vue 3 Typescript Add event listener to html element that has an id only (do not have access to the element directly)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using a gantt chart, Vue 3 component, that is a module I imported, so I have no access to the underlying html. I am able to see the ids and classes that are used via the the Chrome inspector, but no way to add a ref property or add events (since I don't have access to the html for each element). I used CSS to add a scroll bar to one of the ids, but also need to add an event listener to the element with that specific id. How can I do this in Vue 3 with Typescript? The reason I need to add an event listener is so I can scroll two scroll areas at the same time. I already have the scroll event on my component and need to be able to access the scroll event of the external module html element, as well.

Comment: It all comes down to the API this component exposes. Could you link its docs?

Comment: @venir https://infectoone.github.io/vue-ganttastic/introduction.html#features

Comment: I am the author of the library. I have changed my username on github, hence the URL of the docs has changed: https://zunnzunn.github.io/vue-ganttastic/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it looks like you can't.

Please [read this](https://zunnzunn.github.io/vue-ganttastic/GGanttChart.html) and choose one of the available events. From the docs you've mentioned I can see the following events:

```
mousedown-bar
mouseup-bar
dblclick-bar
mouseenter-bar
mouseleave-bar
dragstart-bar
drag-bar
dragend-bar
contextmenu-bar
```

Also note that how don't need to access a component inner's HTML to understand where to bind events but you can't force events in components that don't emit such events.

Comment: I don't want any of those events. I want the scroll event, as stated in my question. I want the scroll event of only a particular area of component.

Comment: I guess I'll edit the question to address this better; if the even isn't exposed by the component, you can't force it. You best bet is raising an issue to their repo.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, the Vuejs app is just a normal web app so you can do anything with Javascript. So I recommend you to have solid Javascript knowledge along with Vuejs.

To answer your question, you can just get your element by ID and attach any event to it:

```js
const yourElement = document.getElementById('your-element-id')
// make sure the element is exists first
if (yourElement) {
  yourElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Do something
  })
}
```

But you need to guarantee two points to make it work:

- The element has to be **exists** before you access it
- The ID is the same at anytime

To ensure the first point you should access your element after rendering the chart. A `nextTick` or `setTimeout` should be useful here.

For the second point, it depends on the library you are using.